# How to do condition check in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE BRANDACTIVITYTYPE(
    BRANDID VARCHAR2(50),
    ACTIVITYCODE VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_BRANDACTY primary key(BRANDID, ACTIVITYCODE),
    CONSTRAINT FK_BRAND_BRANDACTY FOREIGN KEY (BRANDID) REFERENCES BRAND(BID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ACTIVITYCODE_BRANDACTY FOREIGN KEY (ACTIVITYCODE) REFERENCES ACTIVITYTYPE(ACTIVITYCODE) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And the current data the table holds below:

| BRANDID | ACTIVITYCODE |
| --- | --- |
| b01 | A01 |
| b01 | A02 |
| b02 | A01 |
| b02 | A02 |

Now, I have written a stored procedure to check  if new inserted row `brandId` and `ActivityCode` is already present or not in BRANDACTIVITYTYPE table. If present, then there's no need to insert the tuple in another table.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE add_re_rule
(
    brandId IN VARCHAR2,
    activityCode IN VARCHAR2,
    points IN NUMBER,
    ret OUT INT
) 
AS
SAMERULECOUNT INT;
ACTYPECOUNT INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(BRANDID) INTO ACTYPECOUNT FROM BRANDACTIVITYTYPE WHERE BRANDID = brandId AND ACTIVITYCODE = activityCode;
    SELECT COUNT(BRANDID) INTO SAMERULECOUNT FROM RERULE WHERE BRANDID = brandId AND ACTIVITYCODE = activityCode;
    
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(ACTYPECOUNT);

    IF SAMERULECOUNT > 0 THEN
        ret := 0;
    ELSIF ACTYPECOUNT = 0 THEN 
        ret := 2;
    ELSE
        -- Insert into rerule table
        INSERT INTO RERULE(BRANDID, ACTIVITYCODE, POINTS, VERSIONNO) values (brandId, activityCode, points, 1);
        ret := 1;
    END IF;    
END;
/
```

When I run below query, it return 0 which is correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(BRANDID) FROM BRANDACTIVITYTYPE WHERE BRANDID = 'b01' AND ACTIVITYCODE = 'A05';
```

But, when I run the stored procedure, it returns 4 means all the tuple count of the BRANDACTIVITYTYPE table which is wrong and goes into the else condition. It should return 0.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE ret int;
BEGIN
   add_re_rule('b01', 'A05', 60, ret);
END;
```

```
Error starting at line : 32 in command -
DECLARE ret int;
BEGIN
  add_re_rule('b01', 'AOS', 60, ret);
END;
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (C##SCOTT.FK_ACTIVITYCODE_RE) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at "C##SCOIT.ADD RE RULE", line 23
ORA-06512: at line 3
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) viclated - parent key not found"
*Cause: A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action: Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Never name parameters and variables as the corresponding column names. How should Oracle know if it is a parameter or a table column? This is constant true unless you have null in either column: `WHERE BRANDID = brandId AND ACTIVITYCODE = activityCode`

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion worked

Comment: Next time when asking a question, please refer to the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. To summarize: Please do not post images of code or results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the same names for the parameter of the procedure and the column names and therefore the where clause of for example `SELECT COUNT(BRANDID) INTO SAMERULECOUNT FROM RERULE WHERE BRANDID = brandId AND ACTIVITYCODE = activityCode;` will not do as intended.
Just change the names of the parameter.

Comment: Tried. Not working

Comment: I should have tested it, but maybe you want to change the parameter names and I'm pretty sure that should do the trick.

Comment: Yes changing the parameter name worked.